# Is a single-word sentence like "No" an independent clause? And semicolons

Tags: grammar, semicolons, clauses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma or semicolon after “No” when responding to a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78532/comma-or-semicolon-after-no-when-responding-to-a-question)

It started because of this:

"No; I found the behavior off-putting."

1. I believe "no", as an answer, can stand alone.
2. I believe a semicolon is more appropriate than a comma, because of my intent.

Therefore, I ask:

1. Is the semicolon okay?
2. What is "no" called here? It expresses a complete thought, but doesn't fit the textbook definition of an independent clause. Is it clausey?
3. If the semicolon is okay, how would its usage here be described (in grammatical terms)?

Comment: I don't know what the downvote was for; the question is useful and clear. Have an upvote.

Comment: I may put a bounty on that question, then; I was not satisfied with it when I read it a day or two ago. I'll go over it a bit more, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Yes, it's fine. Semicolons are OK wherever there is a [full stop intonation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf); they indicate that "there is still some question about the preceding full sentence; something needs to be added", as [Lewis Thomas](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html) puts it.
>
> 2) *"No;"* is called an ***Utterance***. As you point out, it's not a clause -- no subject, no verb, etc. -- much less a sentence. But it **does** get full-stop intonation, and it's exactly the sort of definitive but uninformational utterance that invite a semicolon to mark the explanation or other expansion of the utterance. But only in writing -- in speech we can't tell semicolons from periods anyway.
>
> 3) The usage of semicolons is described by saying it requires a full-stop intonation. That's not exactly grammatical, but it does have the benefit of being true. If you pronounce an utterance that's correctly punctuated with a semicolon, it will be indistinguishable audibly from a period, or full stop.

That's all because semicolons are technological, not grammatical. Grammar is about real, i.e, **spoken** language, not written language; written language **represents** spoken language, not the other way around.

Pronunciation often shapes, and masks, the punctuation, spelling, and formal usages of an orthography; a good example is the similarities and differences between definite and indefinite articles in English.

Everybody knows that there are two versions of the **indefinite** article: *a* and *an*.

Fewer people know the actual rule for their use, though native speakers can be said to "know" it in some way, because they use it correctly. It's simple, but requires one to consider pronunciation:

> *a* /ə/ occurs before phonetic **consonants**, and *an* /ən/ before phonetic **vowels**.

Spelling is irrelevant; *an hour* but *a utility*.

Fewer people still, however -- most of them non-native speakers -- know that there is a completely parallel rule for **definite** article: *the* and *the*

> *the* is pronounced /ðə/ before phonetic **consonants** and /ði/ before phonetic **vowels**.

Spelling is equally irrelevant: it's /ði'awr/ but /ðəyu'tɪləti/. However, native speakers rarely notice this difference in pronunciation, thinking of both *the*'s as "the same word" because they're spelled the same. If they **are** both "the same word", then so are *a* and *an*.

Comment: "[...] semicolons are technological, not grammatical." Interesting; I hadn't thought about it like that.

Comment: If you're going to edit after over two years, expect comeback. Arguably, there are three _a_ 's also (and **three** _the_'s).

Comment: What are they, then?

Comment: Come on, @Edwin Ashworth, when John Lawler asks a question, we expect an answer!

Comment: Indefinite article: /ə/ in normal conversation, /æ/ when drawn out (eg when considering the next word);  /eɪ/ for emphasis (and quite common, I'd say, in the US). The emphatic form of the definite article is  /ðɪə/ (I assume I'm not misusing the slashes).

Comment: There are lotsa local and special-use allomorphs available. In my idiolect, /ei~æn/ appears for emphasis -- that's the only place I ever use /æ/  for _a/an_ -- but the emphatic _the_ is simply /ði/, without shwa glide. But we haven't discussed nasalization yet, and that varies too.